# The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsurlconnection, ios8

I'm creating a custom keyboard for iOS8, and I'm having a tough time figuring out some issues with NSURLConnection.

I'm using the sendAsynchronousRequest: method like this:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        NSLog(@"recieved asynchronous response");

        if (!connectionError) {
            [self connection:nil didReceiveData:data];
            [self connectionDidFinishLoading:nil];
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"connection failed - %@", connectionError);
        }
    }];
```

This all seems to work correctly for a period of time (1-2 days), and I can correctly receive data. After this time I start seeing the following error message:

```
 ***cachedResponseForRequest:key:handler failed:
```

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4099.)" 
(The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.) UserInfo=0x17579030 
{NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.}; {
    NSDebugDescription = "The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.";

The only way I then seem to be able to make things work correctly again is to reset the content and setting on the phone. If anyone could point me in the correct direction as to why this is happening I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: just turning full access off, and then again turning it helps; but it's not really a solution

Comment: Consider this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26830648/couldn-t-communicate-with-a-helper-application-on-10-10

Answer (score 7):

This occures because the device didn't allow your keyboard to use internet.

To fix this, first check that your keyboard extention's Info.plist has the value "YES" for the key "RequestsOpenAccess".

Then, after installing your app on a device, go to Settings -> General -> Keyboard -> Keyboards -> , and turn on the "Allow Full Access" button.

Comment: It's not the case, cause he mentioned that "This all seems to work correctly for a period of time (1-2 days), and I can correctly receive data.", so he already gave this permission.

Comment: Then maybe he deleted the app in the simulator and thus had to give this permission again :s

Comment: This helped me. Note that the `RequestsOpenAccess` is nested within the `NSExtensionAttributes` dictionary (which itself is withing `NSExtension`)

Answer (score 6):

I also had this problem. When I write a widget for my app, the widget can use network. Then I found how to allow to use network.

Just choose your Target(keyboard) -> Capabilities -> Switch on App Sandbox -> check Network. Incoming Connections(Server) Outgoing Coonections(Client)

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. When I write a widget for my app, the widget can use network. Then I found how to allow to use network.

Just choose your Target(keyboard) -> Capabilities -> Switch on App Sandbox -> check Network.
Incoming Connections(Server)
Outgoing Coonections(Client)

Sorry ^_^, now I can't upload image(because I sign up just now).

Answer (score 0):

I've found the way to avoid the issue.

To solve the issue, add an environment variable before launching tests as follows:

> XPC_SIMULATOR_LAUNCHD_NAME="com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.04042E78-E743-4376-94E9-31842D4770B6.launchd_sim"

However, the **`04042E78-E743-4376-94E9-31842D4770B6`** is depends on each environment. So it can not be hard-coded. I'm looking for a way to read the value from project settings.

Comment: Interesting, can you offer any more details on what this does? I haven't been able to find much documentation for XPC_SIMULATOR_LAUNCHD_NAME yet.