# Unable to download ipa on some iPhone devices OTA, but side loading gets successful

Tags: ios, iphone, ota

Error getting NanoAppRegistry workspace info: Error

> Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named
>   com.apple.nanoappregistry.workspace was invalidated."
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named
>   com.apple.nanoappregistry.workspace was invalidated.}

The OTA link generated is a valid one, as it is able to install on some devices

The same ipa gets successfully installed when its side loaded

Not related to any Keyboard access

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25796041/the-connection-to-service-named-com-apple-nsurlstorage-cache-was-invalidated)

Comment: No, this is related to the topic that you have mentioned @JimmyJames